# Look-and-say sequence: roman numerals edition

Tags: code-golf, sequence, roman-numerals

## Challenge description

We've had a few challenges involving the [Look-and-say sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Look-and-say_sequence). Quick reminder:

- The sequence starts with `1`,
- Subsequent terms of this sequence are generated by enumerating each group of repeating digits in the previous term,

So the first few terms are:

```
1        "one"
11       "one one" (we look at the previous term)
21       "two ones"
1211     "one two, one one"
111221   "one one, one two, two ones"
312211   "three ones, two twos, one one"
```

Now let's do the same thing, but use [Roman Numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals) instead. We start with `I` and follow the same rules (we apply the digit-counting rule to characters instead, so we read `IVX` as `one one, one five, one ten` instead of `one four, one ten` or some other way):

```
I           "one"
II          "one one"
III         "two ones" = "II" + "I"
IIII        "three ones" = "III" + "I"
IVI         "four ones" = "IV" + "I"
IIIVII      "one one, one five, one one"
IIIIIVIII   "three ones, one five, two ones" = ("III" + "I") + ("I" + "V") + ("II" + "I")
```

Given a positive integer `N`, either:

- Output first `N` numerals of this sequence (any reasonable separator is fine, as well as `["I", "II", "III", ...]`
- Output `N`th term of this sequence (it may be 0-indexed).

Remember to make your code as short as possible, since this is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge!

EDIT: I believe that there is always one standard/preferred way of expressing integers as roman numerals, (like `95` -> `XCV` instead of `VC`). Couple of Roman numeral converters I found online corroborate my opinion. If in doubt, use [an online converter](http://www.onlineconversion.com/roman_numerals_advanced.htm), as listing all the possible edge-cases and specific rules of writing Roman numerals is not the point of this challenge.

EDIT2: @PeterTaylor and @GregMartin pointed out that only numbers less or equal to `5` appear in the sequence, so you don't have to worry about the ambiguity of Roman numerals (numbers `1` - `8` are `I`, `II`, `III`, `IV`, `V`, `VI`, `VII`, and `VIII`)

Comment: There isn't a unique Roman numeral expression for each integer. Which numbers might it be necessary to express, and which expressions of those numbers are valid?

Comment: What do you mean by "there isn't a unique Roman numeral expression for each integer"? Like `4` / `IV` / `IIII` ? Or `95` / `XCV` / `VC` ? There might not always be a unique way to express an integer, but I'm pretty sure there's always a preferred (standard) one - correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: how far do we have to go with our roman numberals?

Comment: Yes, both of those cases. In the second case, I think it's very much a matter of opinion which is preferable.

Comment: @Maltysen I think the number of equal digits that can appear in succession is limited to 7.

Comment: @shooqie I agree with you on this one, but you might just want to solidify the rules for roman numerals in OP.

Comment: @Maltysen: Like, this is something that bothers me the most about this site. Make a challenge a tiny bit more complicated and you get questions like `what counts as X?` or `what about the edge-case #98752314?`

Comment: @shooqie if these details weren't clarified, how would you compare answers? If there are certain edge cases left up to interpretation the actual scores become meaningless because they might make a bigger difference than any golfing tricks you could come up with.

Comment: @MartinEnder: Well, I did my best at clearing up the confusion about the Roman numerals, but I feel like I shouldn't have to say how to write them - we've had challenges with Roman numerals before and there didn't seem to be any confusion whatsoever.

Comment: I don't understand the output format - are we converting to roman numerals, grouping by character type, counting the length of each group and turning the whole thing into roman numerals again?

Comment: @muddyfish: Yeah, pretty much.

Comment: I think one can mathematically prove that numbers greater than 8 never appear in the sequence starting at `I`. If so, then programs need only consider `I`s and `V`s.

Comment: @GregMartin, it's possible to prove the stronger statement that no run-length greater than 5 appears in the sequence whose first generation is `I`.

Comment: 1k rep! Congrats :)

Comment: @GregMartin: Well, that certainly makes things easier.

Comment: Surprisingly roman numerals are in fact a decimal notation where a number is split into powers of 10. So `999` = `900+90+9` = `CM + XC + IX` = `CMXCIX` and not `IM` (This is the modern standard form. The romans themselves were not completely consistent). But as noted this is not needed here.

Answer (score 18):

## Perl, 49 bytes

Includes +1 for `-p`

Run with the 0-based index on STDIN, e.g.

```
ecce.pl <<< 14
```

`ecce.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -p
s,(.)\1*,$&/$1%182 .$1,eg for($_=/$/)x$`;y;19;IV
```

Magic formulas are so magic.

Normally I would use `($_=//)x$'` to make the loop control one byte shorter, but scoring on this site gives that a handicap of 2 so it ends up 1 byte longer. On older perls you can drop the space before `for`. Some versions of perl force you to add a final `;` to close the transliteration. But what is given above is the code that works on my system.

### Explanation

Working backwards from solution to code:

The string transformations we need:

```
I     -> II
II    -> III
III   -> IIII
IIII  -> IVI
IIIII -> VI

V     -> IV
VV    -> IIV
```

Each replacement ends with the repeated character. I will get a sequence of the same characters using regex `/(.)\1*/`, so this can be done by appending `$1`. The part before the `->` is in `$&`. With that I still need:

```
I     -> I
II    -> II
III   -> III
IIII  -> IV
IIIII -> V

V     -> I
VV    -> II
```

Write `I` as `1` and `V` as 9:

```
1     -> 1
11    -> 11
111   -> 111
1111  -> 19
11111 -> 9

9     -> 1
99    -> 11
```

By dividing the part before `->` by the repeated digit this becomes:

```
1     -> 1
11    -> 11
111   -> 111
1111  -> 19
11111 -> 9

1     -> 1
11    -> 11
```

So now the original repeated `V` is not an exception anymore. So I want an expression that makes this happen:

```
1     -> 1
11    -> 11
111   -> 111
1111  -> 19
11111 -> 9
```

And this can be done by a simple modulo 182:

```
1     % 182 = 1
11    % 182 = 11
111   % 182 = 111
1111  % 182 = 19
11111 % 182 = 9
```

(this even gets `IIIIII` to `VI` right though it isn't needed here)

All that is left is initializing the working variable to `1` for index 0, repeat this transformation in a loop and at the end replace `1` by `I` and `9` by `V`

`1`, `9` and `182` is the only parameter combination for which this simple formula works.

Comment: This is genius! :)

Answer (score 10):

## Mathematica, <s>113</s> <s>90</s> 83 bytes

*Thanks to Martin Ender for suggestions that reduced the length by over 25%!*

Showing off the high-level commands in Mathematica.

```
Nest[Flatten[Characters@{RomanNumeral@#,#2}&@@@Reverse@@@Tally/@Split@#]&,{"I"},#]&
```

A pure function, taking an argument N and outputting the Nth element of this (0-indexed) sequence, as a list of characters. Spread out a bit:

```
Nest[
  Flatten[
    Characters @ {RomanNumeral@#,#2}& @@@
      Reverse @@@ Tally /@ Split@ #
    ]& ,
  {"I"}, #]&
```

The outer `Nest` iterates the middle four-line function, starting on `{"I"}`, N times. Line 4 splits the character list of the input Roman numeral into runs of like characters, counts each run with `Tally`, and puts the counts before the characters they're counting. Line 3 renders the counts as Roman numerals, then splits those Roman numerals up into lists of characters. The `Flatten` command reduces the whole list-of-lists to a one-dimensional list.

Here's the initial version:

```
Nest[
  "" <> Flatten[{RomanNumeral@#[[1]], #[[2]]} & /@
    (Reverse@#[[1]] & /@ 
      Tally /@
        Split@Characters@#)] &,
  "I", #] &
```

Comment: Grrr Mathematica ;)

Comment: If you use `@@@` instead of `/@` you can use `#` and `#2` instead of `#[[1]]` and `#[[2]]`. Also, lists of characters are acceptable string types, so you can work with those and avoid using `Characters@`.

Comment: @MartinEnder Aha, I knew there must have been a `@@@`-like shortcut! As for lists of characters being acceptable string types (which I agree would shorten the code): is there a post on this site you can point me to that describes the community standard(s)?

Comment: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2216/8478

Comment: A few more savings: `Characters` threads automatically so you can use `@`, `Reverse@#&` is of course the same as plain `Reverse`, in which case you also don't need those parentheses. And prefix notation (in the case of `Flatten`) doesn't save anything if you need to add parentheses to make it work. Combining all of those: `Nest[Flatten[Characters@{RomanNumeral@#,#2}&@@@Reverse@@@Tally/@Split@#]&,{"I"},#]&`

Answer (score 8):

### CJam (<strike>33</strike> 30 bytes)

```
"I"{e`{(4md1$^'I*\'V*@}%e_}ri*
```

[Online demo](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%22I%22%7Be%60%7B(4md1%24%5E'I*%5C'V*%40%7D%25e_%7Dri*&input=5)

Key to the correctness of the implementation is the following theorem:

#### If the first generation is `I`, no run length is ever greater than five

Lemma: if the first generation is `I`, no string ever contains `VVV`. Proof is by contradiction. Suppose that there is a first index `n` for which the `n`th generation contains `VVV`. If that `VVV` breaks down as `(a)V VV` then the conversion  from the previous generation is bad: it should have been `(a+5)V`. So it must be `VV V(d)`, and the previous generation contained `VVVVV`, contradicting the choice of `n`.

Now, suppose there is a first index `m` for which the `m`th generation contains `...IIIIII...`. Note that there can be no digits other than `I` and `V` in the string, because no previous generation has had a run of nine `I`s or nine `V`s. At most four of the `I`s come from a run of `I`s in the previous string, so the corresponding section of the previous string must be `...IIIVV...` giving `... IIII IIV ...`. Since the `VV` in generation `m-1` doesn't come from `VVVVV` (see lemma), the second `V` must be a run-length of digit `I`, so in generation `m-1` we have `...IIIVVI...`. And since we want the initial `I`s to give `IIII` and not `IVI` or `VI`, it is preceded either by the start of the string or by a `V`.

If we have `(...V)?IIIVVI...` in generation `m-1`, what do we have in generation `m-2`? We've already observed that the `VV` of gen. `m-1` must be parsed as `(a)V V(I)`.

Suppose we take `a=2`: `(...V)?I IIV VI...` Actually it must be `...VI IIV VI...`, although that leading `V` might be part of `IV`; so in the previous generation we have either `(...V)? IIII VV IIIII...` or `(...V)? IIIII VV IIIII`. Either way we run into trouble with `VVIIIII`: the second `V` must be a run-length, but then `...VI IIII...` requires a following (run-length, digit) pair with the same digit.

So it must be `a=1`: `(...V)?II IV VI...`. Since generation `m` is the first with a run of six `I`s, that must be `(...V)? II IV VI...`, so that generation `m-2` is `(...V)? I V IIIII...`. `...VIVIIIII...` is impossible: however we choose to interpret the second `V` we end up with two consecutive (run-length, digit) pairs with the same digit.

Therefore generation `m-2` must be `^IVIIIII...`, parsed as `^IV IIII I(V)...` or `^IV III II(V)...`. These give respectively generation `m-3` as `^V III V ...` or `^V II VV...`.

But if we look at the start of the strings beginning with the first one that starts with `V`, we get a cycle:

```
    VI IV I...
    IV III IV ...
    II IV IVI ...
    IIII IV II IV ...
```

and so no generation ever starts with either `VIIIV` or `VIIVV`. We must conclude that there is no such `m`.

#### Dissection

```
"I"          e# Initial generation
{            e# Loop...
  e`         e#   Run-length encode
  {          e#   Foreach [run-length char] pair...
    (        e#     Extract the run-length r
    4md1$^   e#     Get the number of Vs and the number of Is
             e#     The number of Vs is r/4 ; the number of Is is (r%4)^(r/4)
    'I*\'V*@ e#     Repeat strings the appropriate number of times and reorder
  }%
  e_         e#  Flatten to a simple string
}ri*         e# ... n times, where n is taken from stdin
```

Answer (score 6):

## Python 3, 195 bytes

There's a lot of bytes wasted on the roman numerals, so there's likely some golfing to be done there.

Thanks to @El'endiaStarman, @Sherlock9 and @Shooqie

```py
import re
def f(x,r=""):
 for v,i in(5,"V"),(4,"IV"),(1,"I"):a,x=divmod(x,v);r+=i*a
 return r
s="I"
for i in[0]*int(input()):print(s);s=re.sub(r'(.)\1*',lambda m:f(len(m.group()))+m.group()[0],s)
```

[**Ideone it!**](https://ideone.com/ka3vCW)

Comment: You can omit square brackets: `for v,i in(5,"V"),(4,"IV"),(1,"I")`

Comment: @shooqie I had no idea that you could do that :D

Comment: `for v,i in(5,"V"),(4,"IV"),(1,"I"):a,x=divmod(x,v);r+=i*a` saves a byte.

Comment: @βετѧΛєҫαγ: Also, you're not seem to be using `i` (as in `for i in range(...)`). I tried dabbling with `exec` but this escaped `1` in the 'sub' method seems to be messing up the code, I haven't been able to find a workaround.

Comment: @shooqie I shortened it a bit by getting rid of `range`

Comment: Hi, next time you might want to cross-out the previous byte-counts when improvements are made. I.e. **Python 3, <s>314</s> <s>210</s> <s>202</s> <s>200</s> <s>199</s> 196 bytes**. A.f.a.i.k. it's kinda standard to do so here on PPCG.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Nah, there isn't a standard on PPCG, and I prefer to keep it neater

Answer (score 4):

### R, <s>110</s> 107 Bytes

`as.roman` combined with `rle` makes this easy. Scoping abuse and built in cat behavior of `<<-` saves a few bytes.

```
x="I"
replicate(scan(),{r=rle(strsplit(x,"")[[1]])
x<<-paste(rbind(paste(as.roman(r$l)),r$v),collapse="")})
```

Takes in N from console. Outputs first 2 to N terms of sequence (which I believe is within spec...)

```
 [1] "II"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
 [2] "III"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
 [3] "IIII"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
 [4] "IVI"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
 [5] "IIIVII"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
 [6] "IIIIIVIII"                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
 [7] "VIIVIIII"                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
 [8] "IVIIIIVIVI"                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
 [9] "IIIVIVIIVIIIVII"                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
[10] "IIIIIVIIIVIIIIVIIIIIVIII"                                                                                                                                                                                                               
[11] "VIIVIIIIIVIVIIVVIIVIIII"                                                                                                                                                                                                                
[12] "IVIIIIVVIIVIIIVIIIIIVIIIIVIVI"                                                                                                                                                                                                          
[13] "IIIVIVIIIVIIIIVIIIIIVVIIVIVIIVIIIVII"                                                                                                                                                                                                   
[14] "IIIIIVIIIVIIIIIVIVIIVVIIIVIIIIVIIIVIIIIVIIIIIVIII"                                                                                                                                                                                      
[15] "VIIVIIIIIVVIIVIIIVIIIIIVIIIIIVIVIIVIIIIIVIVIIVVIIVIIII"                                                                                                                                                                                 
[16] "IVIIIIVVIIIVIIIIVIIIIIVVIIVVIIVIIIVIIIIVVIIVIIIVIIIIIVIIIIVIVI"                                                                                                                                                                         
[17] "IIIVIVIIIVIIIIIVIVIIVVIIIVIIIIIVIIIIVIIIIIVIVIIIVIIIIVIIIIIVVIIVIVIIVIIIVII"                                                                                                                                                            
[18] "IIIIIVIIIVIIIIIVVIIVIIIVIIIIIVIIIIIVVIIVIVIIVVIIVIIIVIIIIIVIVIIVVIIIVIIIIVIIIVIIIIVIIIIIVIII"                                                                                                                                           
[19] "VIIVIIIIIVVIIIVIIIIVIIIIIVVIIVVIIIVIIIIVIIIVIIIIIVIIIIVIIIIIVVIIVIIIVIIIIIVIIIIIVIVIIVIIIIIVIVIIVVIIVIIII"                                                                                                                              
[20] "IVIIIIVVIIIVIIIIIVIVIIVVIIIVIIIIIVIIIIIVIVIIVIIIIIVVIIVIVIIVVIIIVIIIIVIIIIIVVIIVVIIVIIIVIIIIVVIIVIIIVIIIIIVIIIIVIVI"                                                                                                                    
[21] "IIIVIVIIIVIIIIIVVIIVIIIVIIIIIVIIIIIVVIIVVIIVIIIVIIIIVVIIIVIIIIVIIIVIIIIIVIIIIIVIVIIVVIIIVIIIIIVIIIIVIIIIIVIVIIIVIIIIVIIIIIVVIIVIVIIVIIIVII"                                                                                             
[22] "IIIIIVIIIVIIIIIVVIIIVIIIIVIIIIIVVIIVVIIIVIIIIIVIIIIVIIIIIVIVIIIVIIIIIVIVIIVIIIIIVVIIVVIIVIIIVIIIIIVIIIIIVVIIVIVIIVVIIVIIIVIIIIIVIVIIVVIIIVIIIIVIIIVIIIIVIIIIIVIII"                                                                      
[23] "VIIVIIIIIVVIIIVIIIIIVIVIIVVIIIVIIIIIVIIIIIVVIIVIVIIVVIIVIIIVIIIIIVVIIVIIIVIIIIVVIIIVIIIIIVIIIIVIIIIIVVIIVVIIIVIIIIVIIIVIIIIIVIIIIVIIIIIVVIIVIIIVIIIIIVIIIIIVIVIIVIIIIIVIVIIVVIIVIIII"                                                   
[24] "IVIIIIVVIIIVIIIIIVVIIVIIIVIIIIIVIIIIIVVIIVVIIIVIIIIVIIIVIIIIIVIIIIVIIIIIVVIIIVIIIIVIIIIIVIVIIIVIIIIIVVIIVIVIIVVIIIVIIIIIVIIIIIVIVIIVIIIIIVVIIVIVIIVVIIIVIIIIVIIIIIVVIIVVIIVIIIVIIIIVVIIVIIIVIIIIIVIIIIVIVI"                             
[25] "IIIVIVIIIVIIIIIVVIIIVIIIIVIIIIIVVIIVVIIIVIIIIIVIIIIIVIVIIVIIIIIVVIIVIVIIVVIIIVIIIIIVIVIIVVIIVIIIVIIIIIVVIIIVIIIIVIIIVIIIIIVIIIIIVVIIVVIIVIIIVIIIIVVIIIVIIIIVIIIVIIIIIVIIIIIVIVIIVVIIIVIIIIIVIIIIVIIIIIVIVIIIVIIIIVIIIIIVVIIVIVIIVIIIVII"
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 62 bytes

```
{("I",{S:g/(.)$0*/{<I II III IV V>[$/.chars-1]~$0}/}...*)[$_]}
```

Anonymous function that accepts a zero-based index.

Makes use of the fact that roman numbers higher than 5 aren't needed, because the only groups of repeating digits that can occur, are:

```
I     -> II
II    -> III
III   -> IIII
IIII  -> IVI
IIIII -> VI

V     -> IV
VV    -> IIV
```

([try it online](https://glot.io/snippets/ei0b53qvr2))

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 107

Recursive function returning the Nth term 0 based

```js
f=(n,r='I')=>n?f(n-1,r.match(/I+|V+/g).map(x=>((n=x.length)-4?'VIII'.slice(n<5,1+n%5):'IV')+x[0]).join``):r
```

**Test**

```js
f=(n,r='I')=>n?f(n-1,r.match(/I+|V+/g).map(x=>((n=x.length)-4?'VIII'.slice(n<5,1+n%5):'IV')+x[0]).join``):r

function update() {
  O.textContent=f(I.value)
}

update()
```

```html
<input id=I value=25 type=number oninput='update()'><pre id=O></pre>
```